# With an internal nuxt-link, how to append the whole hostname URL rather than just the path?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-middleware

I've a simple problem:
When my Nuxt site is deployed, all the `NuxtLink`s are converted to `<a href="">` tags. But the URL in `href` is relative.

For example: (Refer Image - ss1.png)
The URL is `/calculators/sip`.

[image]

What my requirement is, I need these URLs to be absolute, i.e., the URL should contains domain name also.

For example: The rendered URL should look like:
`<a href="https://example.com/calculators/sip/">` through out my site.

Bascially, all the URLs/NuxtLink should have domain name attached to it . As per my understanding of Nuxt Docs.

I need to add `router.base: 'https://example.com/'` in `nuxt.config.js` file. But that is create more problem.

Instead of generting  `<a href="https://example.com/calculators/sip/">` it is prepending `/` in the anchor tag like `<a href="/https://example.com/calculators/sip/">`.

PS: we are using Nuxt2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve this

```html
<nuxt-link v-slot="{ route, navigate }" to="/calculators" custom>
  <a :href="'https://nuxt2-nuxtlink-repro.netlify.app' + '/calculators'" @click="navigate">
    Go to {{ route.fullPath }}
  </a>
  <a @click="navigate">Go to {{ route.fullPath }} (different way)</a>
</nuxt-link>
```

Where rather than having just the path aka `<a href="/calculators"></a>`, you have a whole
`<a href="https://nuxt2-nuxtlink-repro.netlify.app/calculators"></a>`

Here is a [working repro](https://github.com/kissu/nuxt2-nuxtlink-repro) hosted [on Netlify](https://nuxt2-nuxtlink-repro.netlify.app/).
And here is the [official resource](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#v-slot-api-3-1-0) regarding the vue-router part.